# Google Sheets: average cells in Row 4 up to last filled cell in Row 2

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to write a Formula in Google Sheets which calculates the average of the cells in Row 4 but only up to the last filled cell in Row 2?

Comment: I'm sure some sample data would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=AVERAGE(FILTER(4:4, LEN(2:2)))
```

and see if that works for you.

### Explanation

- FILTER(4:4, LEN(2:2))

This part filters row 4 so that it has the same amount of cells as the non-blank cells in row2. Whether a cell (in row 2) is blank or not is checked with the len function, that will return 0 (no LENGTH) for empty cells.

- AVERAGE(FILTER(4:4, LEN(2:2)))

The above function is wrapped in an average-function...

Comment: This would be an awesome answer with some explanation of how the functions work.

Comment: @AlE.You are right. Explanation added.

Comment: @truedson. Glad to hear ! You are most welcome.